# Kill YARN application according to user name

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am looking for a way to kill all YARN applications coming from a specific user.
I know that I can use `yarn application -kill [application_ID]` command but I have a list of jobs coming from the same user I'd like to kill (all of them).

More precisely, I would like for instance to kill all jobs coming from dr.who.
[image]

Is there any way to do that without killing job one by one?
Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

My question was asked because one user was submitting unwilling jobs. I wanted to kill them all while I was changing security settings (set up a firewall and blocked everything from outside).

I had to use indeed a workaround to kill running jobs while I was setting the network with a script based on `yarn application -kill` , `yarn application -list | grep "dr.who"`and `awk`. That script is certainly not a good solution.

Comment: i'd use bash-scripting for that, some combination of `yarn application -list` and `grep` or `awk`

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in `yarn application -list | grep -w dr.who | grep -E -o application_[0-9,_]*`; do yarn application -kill $i; done
```

Comment: It is what I did as a work around but I don't think this is the best way to avoid one specific user to submit jobs.